# What exactly is the meaning of the phrase "county courted"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I come across this phrase very rarely, most recently in a Wodehouse story. It seems to mean something like "brought as defendant before a county court", e.g., sued. Is there a more precise meaning? In Wodehouse it arises when a character fails to pay his bills and is county courted by his tailor, or something like that. Is a county court something like a small claims court? Can one be county courted for theft, for nonpayment of taxes, for speeding, for murder? What is the level of such a court in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

The Victorian weekly literary magazine *[All the Year Round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_Year_Round)*, edited by Charles Dickens, has an interesting passage found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=F4NGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA440&dq=%22county%20courted%22&hl=en):

> The fact is, that Growler had been “County Courted.” (“To County
>   Court,” I may observe in parenthesis, is a verb only admissible into
>   dictionaries of recent date.

I am not sure which dictionaries are meant here, since none of those I checked have such entry. Still, the meaning is clear from the context, as well as from other occurrences of the same phrase found on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22county+courted%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks), e.g.:

> Let it once be known that a trader has been “County Courted ” and his
>   destruction is inevitable,
>
> Otherwise, he remarked, he might be "county courted" for a debt he
>   could not pay. There was also a great deal of evidence as to the
>   inferiority of goods supplied by tallymen upon the credit system, and
>   among the witnesses was Mr. Commissioner Kerr,
>
> Some debtors talked of being 'county courted'. For instance, Debtor 11
>   said, 'I knew you'd get county courted. That's obvious, everybody
>   knows that.'
>
> The reason why one debtor can be county courted and another cannot
>   lies in the amount of the debt;

---

The nature and jurisdiction of county courts is IMHO adequately covered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_court).